# Meta tables for Spring Batch not created by Hibernate4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

EDIT: ALthough i think hibernate should be able to do this automatically, i have a DDL scri[pt containing the structure I need. If i can run this script so that hibernate automatically create the tables, i'm happy for now... `[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475714/how-to-get-hibernate-to-create-tables-based-on-ddl-sql-script)

My excuses for the lengthy post. My question, though might be quite simple, but being a hibernate and spring noob, this is bugging me for this whole morning....

I'm using spring batch. When running an import job, Spring wants to store meta data about job excution in a table named BATCH_JOB. However, this table is not created by Hibernate.

I run the job by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean_configuration.xml");
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = (SimpleJobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        FlowJob job = (FlowJob) context.getBean("importIVSJob");
        launcher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
```

My hibernate properties file:

```
#hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
#hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
#hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
#hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

and the xml config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">


        <batch:job job-repository="jobRepository" id="importIVSJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="csvFileReader" writer="itemWriter"
                    commit-interval="5" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="csvFileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" ref="inputResource" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer"
                        p:delimiter=";"
                        p:names="objectcode, event, beginTijd, duurEvent, kolkNummer, deelkolkNummer, vaarrichting, eniNummer, aantalSchepen, scheepType, vaartType, subTypeVaart, rwsKlasseHoofgroep, rwsKlasseSubgroep, cemtKlasse, laadvermogen, dwtLaadvermogen, scheepslengte, scheepsbreedte, scheepsdiepgang, scheepshoogte, vlagCode, beladingsCode, cargoGewicht, seinVoeringKegel, vrachtAanBoord, aantalContainers, aantalTEU_containers, reisId, toerbeurt, invaartGroen, uitvaartGroen" />
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper"
                        p:targetType="nl.triopsys.styx.importeer.IVS.IvsBericht" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" ref="outputResource" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names"
                            value="objectcode, event, beginTijd, duurEvent, kolkNummer, deelkolkNummer, vaarrichting, eniNummer, aantalSchepen, scheepType, vaartType, subTypeVaart, rwsKlasseHoofgroep, rwsKlasseSubgroep, cemtKlasse, laadvermogen, dwtLaadvermogen, scheepslengte, scheepsbreedte, scheepsdiepgang, scheepshoogte, vlagCode, beladingsCode, cargoGewicht, seinVoeringKegel, vrachtAanBoord, aantalContainers, aantalTEU_containers, reisId, toerbeurt, invaartGroen, uitvaartGroen" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="inputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="file:C:\Users\jgoddijn\testdata\IVS90.csv" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="outputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="C:\Users\jgoddijn\testdata\output.csv" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="batch.properties" p:ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/D:/DMVV/HSQLDB;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.importeer.IVS.IvsBericht</value>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.domain.Vaartuig</value>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.domain.AIS.MMSI</value>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.domain.IVS90.valuetype.Scheepsnummer</value>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.domain.IVS90.valuetype.EniNummer</value>
                <value>nl.triopsys.styx.domain.IVS90.valuetype.ImoNummer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
                <property name="location" value="batch.properties" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher"
        p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" />

    <bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
        p:jobRegistry-ref="jobRegistry" />

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

and the error i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy20.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1436)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:714)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:204)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:221)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy19.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:94)
    at nl.triopsys.styx.sandbox.importeer.RunImport.main(RunImport.java:39)
```

It seems that no table is created for the job execution. How to get hibernate to do this automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to specify the script as an initialise parameter on the H2 DB URL:

`jdbc:h2:~/mydb;init=runscript from 'classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql'`

Providing the spring-batch-core jar is on your classpath it will create these tables on the first run of your test. You can then remove it once the tables are created.